# Question about optocoupler and transistor

Tags: voltage, transistors, opto-isolator

i intend to isolate the microcontroller pwm signal, because in reality the V3 source will be a high voltage source, therefore i think i need to isolate the microcontroller in case there's exist leakage in the MOSFET. My question is, will this design works? I want the output from the optocoupler emmiter transistor nearly the same (voltage drop is not a problem), so i can still control the mosfet with the pwm signal also protect the microcontroller from the high voltage. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, You don't need R2. But your high voltage isn't high enough to be a safety issue and I don't see any leakage to worry about. I would just drive M1 directly. If M1 is leaking through the gate, your MOSFET is dead already. If you want to protect your MCU against being damaged by that so you only need to replace MOSFET rather than MOSFET and MCU, a gate resistor and diode clamp will do it. Also, if you PWM you want a gate driver.

Comment: R1 is way too small, but a better way is to eliminate the opto as DKN says.  What is the actual value of V3?  There could be a safety / insulation issue if it is very high, not isolated from the AC mains, etc.  If none of that applies, direct drive is better.

Comment: The latest version of my design the actual value of V3 is 300V DC

Comment: @DKNguyen is it possible(at the worst case), the mosfet broke so the drain and gate connected, therefore the V3(300V DC) voltage flows and if u don't mind to explain the arrangement, does the clamp diode arrangement is the same when i use a clamp diode on solenoid?

Comment: At 300V is different. That's a safety issue so you want opto isolation there. The clamp diode configuration I am talking about is similar to the kind you see for ESD protection. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483959/how-does-esd-protection-work-with-tvs-diodes/483990#483990

Comment: In that case, is the optocoupler is an "okay" solution or using the diode solution is better?

Comment: Diode solution is bad in that case. Use the opto But your V2 needs to be separate from everuthing on the input side of the opto too. Or else if something fails the 300V bypasses the opto through V2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible problem, is that the rise/fall time of the optoisolator
output is specified at 2 us or less, into a 100  ohm load.   Because
you have a 10k ohm load, the rise time could be as much as 200 us,
and that's problematic with a PWM base frequency much  over 1 kHz.

Any slow slewing of the gate of the MOSFET will result in heat
dissipation in that component.   Another photocoupler, like APS1551S,
might be better; there's builtin amplification and low delays.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, really appreciate it!

Comment: I intend to use this circuit as a kicker board (kicker in soccer robot), tbh i haven't count the exact value XD. I wanna ask, if i change the optocoupler to the right specs also the resistor, will this circuit works?

Answer (score 0):

R1 is too small and the drive voltage is too small so it won't work. The infrared LED requires about 1.2V so it can be driven from 3.3V or 5V easily with an appropriate resistor to keep the current at some reasonable value such as 5-10mA. Eg. 510\$\Omega\$ for 5V.

Depending on your PWM frequency, the 4N25 and 10K pull-down may be too sluggish when especially considering the gate charge of the MOSFET. Pull-up will be (relatively) fast. You can simulate this in LTspice.

If  you want a simple bulletproof manner of driving the MOSFET, a purpose-designed isolated gate driver such as the [ADuM4120](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM4120-4120-1.pdf) will work. You can use the 12V for the gate driver if the MOSFET is suitable for that, and reduce the Rds(on) and possibly keep the two supplies completely isolated. The UVLO (undervoltage lockout) is a valuable feature in that it can prevent the MOSFET from being partially turned on in the case of brownout on Vdd2.

[image]

If you want the cheapest possible way there are other ways do accomplish a similar task with more generic parts but more components and more design effort.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Honestly, i haven't calculate the optocoupler resistor XD, i still doesn't understand where i can put the pull up resistor, can u help me a bit about this? and about the switching speed, i design this to used like a HV switch from a charged capacitor (Soccer robot kicker) so i think it'll be open in a short period of time to release the charge and delay more than 1s before it starts switching again to kick. My question is the switching time really a problem in this case? Thanks!

Comment: That may be an okay application since the switch-off time is not so important. You can simulate it and the instantaneous power dissipation in the MOSFET using LTspice. R2 is not necessary (zero ohms).

Comment: Can i ask again XD, thanks for answering me, i wanna ask why R2 is unnecessary? if i omit that resistor won't the current flowing to the collector will be very high?

Comment: No it will be limited by the CTR of the optoisolator and will only persist long enough to supply the gate charge (plus a bit through the 10K which persists).

Comment: i see, thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry sir can i ask again? Does this circuit enough to protect in case the  V3 (reality:300 volt) leak to the gate of the mosfet and will it burn the v2? If so, will combination of diode to block the reverse current and zener diode to lower the reverse voltage will prevent this to happen?

Comment: @AgustinusYudhistira Without protection it could get to V2. A  simple 1kV diode + TVS could definitely help with that.